# "Block"-type template functions

Tags: go

Using `http/template` is it possible to define a "block"-type function that work like the built-in `define` or `range`? For example, I'd like to make a function that works like:

```
<div class="page">
  {{doThing}}
    Large amount of text here...
  {{end}}
</div>
```

I know I can make it work with `{{ doThing "Large amount of text here..." }}`, but that's not quite what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to write a block-type function that works like the built-in define or range actions.